# Bootstrap the Correlation Coefficient without boot() in R

Tags: correlation, bootstrap

I want to understand the bootstrap-method for correlations. Therefore i tried to bootstrap the correlation without the boot() function of R. The problem of bootstrapping correlations are the bivariate data. I found on the internet the following statement:

> There is one point to note: because each observation consists of [two
>   features, variables], we resample the observations [and not each
>   feature]. Resampling [the variables] separately would lose the tie
>   between them.

(Bootstrap Methods and Permutation Tests, Hesterberg 2003). Let's have a look to my example now:

I have the following bivariate data (amount of proline and amount of kollagen):

```
prolin<-read.csv2("Data/Prolin.csv",header=TRUE)

prolin

Prolin Kollagen

1. 7.1  2.8
2. 7.1   2.9
3. 7.2   2.8
4. 8.3   2.6
5. 9.4   3.5
6. 10.5   4.6
7. 11.4   5.0
```

I first created the bootstrap resamples (for example 2000 of them) with the following R-Code. I sample not only a single observation but a whole row (Is this correct?):

```
n=2000
resamples <- lapply(1:n,function(i)prolin[sample(nrow(prolin),7,replace=TRUE),])

resamples[ 1 ]

[[ 1 ]]

Prolin Kollagen

1. 8.3  2.6
2. 10.5   4.6
3. 10.5   4.6
4. 7.1   2.9
5. 11.4   5.0
6. 7.1   2.8
7. 8.3   2.6
```

Then I tried to compute the spearman correlation coefficient to all resamples. Because I had problems with the sapply-function I used a for-loop. Previously I summarized all resamples in a data.frame (to have access to each variable of one resample). Then I compute the correlation coefficient between the first and the second column, the third and the fourth column...of the data frame:

```
DF<-data.frame(resamples[i])

spcorr=vector(length=0)

for(i in 1:n){spcorr[i]<-cor(DF[,2*i-1],DF[,2*i],method="spearman")}
```

The length of spcorr is 2000. The distribution of the vector spcorr should be my sample distribution. The problem is, that the histogram of spcorr is not a normal distribution (but should be) (see picture). What did I misunderstand?

[image: Distribution of spcorr]

Last Qustion: how can i build a 0.95 confidence interval with these data.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The Spearman correlation coefficient cannot possibly have a Normal bootstrap distribution because it is limited to the interval $[-1,1]$ and--with such a small dataset--it necessarily has a wide spread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are my codes correct? Is it possible to create a confidence intervall if the bootstrap distribution is not normal?

Answer (score 5):

As I understand your question, you ask how to implement bootstrap for bivariate correlation. Your text correctly suggests that rather than sampling cases for each of the variables independently (e.g. $x_i, y_j$), you should rather sample pairs of values ($x_i,y_i$). In multivariate case, if your data is stored in a matrix (observations in rows, variables in columns), you sample with replacement $N$ out of $N$ rows of the matrix to create a resampled one. This is shown on the example below.

```r
dat <- mtcars[, c(1, 3)]
N <- nrow(dat)
R <- 2500

cor.orig <- cor(dat)[1,2]
cor.boot <- NULL

for (i in 1:R) {
  idx <- sample.int(N, N, replace = TRUE) 
  cor.boot[i] <- cor(dat[idx, ])[1,2] 
}
```

On the plot below you can see histogram of bootstrapped correlation estimates with the correlation estimate from the raw data marked by red dashed line.

[image]

It is not true that your bootstrap distribution should be normal. I see from your plot that the your correlation estimate is close to $1$. This means that it's bootstrap distributtion simple cannot be symmetric because correlation is bounded in $[-1, 1]$. In such case it will always be skewed and will never look normal-like.

There are multiple ways how you could obtain confidece intervals using bootstrap. The simplest one is to take appropriate quantiles from the bootstrapped sample (i.e. `quantile(cor.boot, c(0.025, 0.975))` in the example). Such method will work for non-normal distributions.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a for loop?