# Bootstrapped p-value for Pearson correlation

Tags: correlation, spss, p-value, bootstrap

I'd like to compute p-values for simple Pearson correlations when using bootstrapping.

Is there any opportunity to do this (I'm using SPSS and the only thing you can do within this software is to compute the CI's)?

Can I just take the p-values that a simple linear regression will give me (SPSS can do this) or is this incorrect?

---

Thanks for your answer.

I'd like to have the p-value as a bootstrapped estimate (just like in the linear regression). The normal p-value gets not bootstrapped as i know, even if the bootstrapped icon is selected.

I need bootstrapping because the assumptions aren't that clealry fulfilled in my data.

So it is not an Option to use the bootstrapped p-value that SPSS gives me for a simple linear Regression?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need the SPSS module for bootstrapping as shown here: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/products/statistics/modules/ at an extra cost.

If you run correlations, SPSS should provide you with the p-values of the correlations. I'm unclear as to why you'd need to bootstrap.

Comment: What is the role of the Pearson correlations in the bootstrapping?  Are you bootstrapping correlations or computing correlations of bootstrapped statistics?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap the Correlation Coefficient without boot() in R](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212380/bootstrap-the-correlation-coefficient-without-boot-in-r)

Comment: $p$-values assume a certain null hypothesis. Bootstrap methods are quite poor in handling hypothesis testing problems, as you would have to align your data to conform to the null.